# Python package: `ImportError: cannot import name 'mod' from partially initialized module 'new_package' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python

I have a repo, which I would like to turn into a package

```
mypackage/
    __init__.py
    multiplication.py
    mod/
        __init__.py
        addition.py
```

The file `mod/addition.py` looks like

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b
```

and the file `mod/__init__.py` is empty.

The file `multiplication.py` looks like

```
def add(a,b):
    return a*b
```

Now when I have as `__init__.py` file

```
from . import multiplication
```

I can add least work with multiplication, when installing it in a Docker image.

However, if it looks like

```
from . import multiplication

from . import mod
```

I get

```
from . import mod
ImportError: cannot import name 'mod' from partially initialized module 'mypackage' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mypackage/__init__.py)
```

Do you know, how what I have to do to be able to use all functions from `mypackage`?

Comment: Your example seems to work for me, so if you've adjusted your real code before posting it here then you might have hidden the actual problem.

Note I'd expect `mod/__init__.py` to have `from .addition import add`, otherwise you won't be able to access `mypackage.mod.add` after doing `import mypackage`.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, what is strange is that it also works for me in the Python console of the project, where I am importing it. However, when starting the docker-container and installing it from git, it causes problems like above.